# How can I return multiple lines JSX in another return statement in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A single line works fine:

```
render: function () {
  return (
    {[1,2,3].map(function (n) {
      return <p>{n}</p>
    }}
  );
}
```

But not for multiple lines:

```
render: function () {
  return (
    {[1,2,3].map(function (n) {
      return (
        <h3>Item {n}</h3>
        <p>Description {n}</p>
      )
    }}
  );
}
```

Comment: For more info on this particular issue: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2127

Comment: not `return ("asdf" "asdf");` you want `return ["asdf", "asdf"];`

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Try to think of the tags as function calls (see [the documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/maximum-number-of-jsx-root-nodes.html)). Then the first one becomes:

```
{[1,2,3].map(function (n) {
  return React.DOM.p(...);
})}
```

And the second one:

```
{[1,2,3].map(function (n) {
  return (
    React.DOM.h3(...)
    React.DOM.p(...)
  )
})}
```

It should now be clear that the second snippet doesn't really make sense (you can't return more than one value in JavaScript). You have to either wrap it in another element (most likely what you'd want, that way you can also provide a valid `key` property), or you can use something like this:

```
{[1,2,3].map(function (n) {
  return ([
    React.DOM.h3(...),
    React.DOM.p(...)
  ]);
})}
```

With [JSX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)#JSX) syntactic sugar:

```
{[1,2,3].map(function (n) {
  return ([
    <h3></h3>, // note the comma
    <p></p>
  ]);
})}
```

You don't need to flatten the resulting array. React will do that for you. See the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mEB2V/1/. Again: Wrapping the two elements into a div/section will most likely be better long term.

Comment: Yep actually clearly documented http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/maximum-number-of-jsx-root-nodes.html

Comment: Using return ([...]) without the flatten bit gives me the markup exactly as I wanted, though the returned array mustn't have been flattend but in my particular case it doesn't affect the final output. Or is it?

Comment: Thanks! TIL! Updating my answer to include a link to a JSFiddle that shows that flatten is optional. Will also include the link to the React docs.

Comment: The second example is missing a closing bracket for the map function: the last line has to be '})}' instead of '}}'. Same goes for the first example.

Comment: This no longer works (as of 0.9ish) `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Product.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

Comment: Returning an array in a ternary seems to be working for me with 0.13.3 — https://gist.github.com/TimFletcher/41299e54373a37873a91

Comment: @TimFletcher It's fine to return an array as *part of* rendering a component, e.g `<div>{ this.props.foos.map(function() { return <Foo /> }) }</div>`. But the `render` function of the component can't return that array without wrapping it, e.g. in a div.

Comment: returning an array works but react complains about the missing keys when flattening the array.

Comment: @JanOlafKrems funny to stumble over you here on stackoverflow! your answer helped me a lot, thanks :)

Comment: More [exact link](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#jsx-children) regarding returning arrays (third example).

Comment: JSX Sugar adds sweetness in my day. Thanks @JanOlafKrems

Answer (score 37):

It seems [Jan Olaf Krems's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840997/how-can-i-return-multiple-lines-jsx-in-another-return-statement-in-react/23841059#23841059) about returning an array no longer applies (maybe since React ~0.9, as @dogmatic69 wrote in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840997/how-to-return-multiple-lines-jsx-in-another-return-statement-in-react/32226265#comment52175067_23841059)).

[The documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/maximum-number-of-jsx-root-nodes.html) says you need to return a single node:

> Maximum Number of JSX Root Nodes
>
> Currently, in a component's render,
> you can only return one node; if you have, say, a list of divs to
> return, you must wrap your components within a div, span or any other
> component.
>
> Don't forget that JSX compiles into regular JS; returning two
> functions doesn't really make syntactic sense. Likewise, don't put
> more than one child in a ternary.

In many cases you can simply wrap things in a `<div>` or a `<span>`.

In my case, I wanted to return multiple `<tr>`s. I wrapped them in a `<tbody>` – a table is allowed to have multiple bodies.

As of React 16.0, returning an array is apparently allowed again, as long as each element has a `key`: *[New render return types: fragments and strings](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#new-render-return-types-fragments-and-strings)*

React 16.2 lets you surround a list of elements with `<Fragment>…</Fragment>` or even `<>…</>`, if you prefer that to an array: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: What can you do if you want to return multiple `<li>`? Assuming that I can't just wrap it all in `<ul>`

Comment: @Banjocat I'm afraid I don't know :/ You are allowed to *nest* lists, so you could return something like `<li><ul><li>one</li><li>two</li></ul></li>` if that works in your situation. Or: A wrapping div wouldn't strictly be valid but maybe it renders fine in all relevant browsers? If you try it, let us know.

Comment: @Banjocat...I'd love to know a better answer to your question. Maybe you should pose it as a regular stackoverflow question and see if you get a different answer.

Comment: @user1175849 Maybe *you* could post that question then :)

Comment: Create a list on the object and return each `<li />` into it. Then when you want to add more, you do `this.listItems.push(<li />)`. If I remember correctly, you can do `<ul>{this.listItems}</ul>`.

Comment: If you want to render a finite number of <div> matching a number not an array, let's say 30. How do you proceed since returning an element in a for loop breaks the loop. ??

Comment: @DragosPodaru You could use `map` if available, or `push` each item onto an array and then return the array. But note that the outermost element needs to be a single node per my answer.

Comment: @HenrikN Fwiw, wrapping a "subset" of `li` in a `span` or `div` didn't work well for me. The div seriously broke rendering, and, at least in my use case, the span messed up the CSS. **2¢:** Trying to return several subsets of `li`s is a code smell. We were using a `ul` as a sort of pull-down menu, and I initially wanted many components to return "sections" of `li`s. In the end, it was better to put all the menu code into a single component "anchored" at `ul` than to shoehorn in `li`s from multiple sources. I think it made also the mental model for the UI a little cleaner.

Comment: The last link seems to be broken: *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at blog.jmes.tech."*

Answer (score 19):

From **React v16.0.0** onwards, it is possible to *return* multiple elements by wrapping them within an `Array`:

```
render() {
  return (
    {[1,2,3].map(function (n) {
      return [
        <h3>Item {n}</h3>.
        <p>Description {n}</p>
      ]
    }}
  );
}
```

Also from **React v16.2.0**, a new feature called [`React Fragments`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) is introduced which you can use to wrap multiple elements:

```
render() {
  return (
    {[1,2,3].map(function (n, index) {
      return (
        <React.Fragment key={index}>
            <h3>Item {n}</h3>
            <p>Description {n}</p>
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    }}
  );
}
```

As per the documentation:

> A common pattern in React is for a component to return multiple
> elements. Fragments let you group a list of children without adding
> extra nodes to the DOM.
>
> Fragments declared with the explicit <React.Fragment> syntax may have
> keys. A use case for this is mapping a collection to an array of
> fragments — for example, to create a description list:
>
> ```
> function Glossary(props) {
>   return (
>     <dl>
>       {props.items.map(item => (
>         // Without the `key`, React will fire a key warning
>         <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
>           <dt>{item.term}</dt>
>           <dd>{item.description}</dd>
>         </React.Fragment>
>       ))}
>     </dl>
>   );
> }
> ```
>
> key is the only attribute that can be passed to Fragment. In the
> future, we may add support for additional attributes, such as event
> handlers.

Answer (score 9):

Also, you might want to return several list items in some helper function inside a React component. Just return an array of HTML nodes with the `key` attribute:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class YourComponent extends Component {
  // ...

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.renderListItems()}
      </ul>
    )
  }

  renderListItems() {
    return [
      <li key={1}><a href="#">Link1</a></li>,
      <li key={2}><a href="#">Link2</a></li>,
      <li key={3} className="active">Active item</li>,
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## Updated

Use React Fragment. It's simple. [Link](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) to fragment documentation.

```
render() {
  return (
    <>
    {[1,2,3].map((value) => <div>{value}</div>)}
    </>
  );
}
```

## Old answer - obsolete

With React > 16 you can use [react-composite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-composite).

```
import { Composite } from 'react-composite';

// ...

{[1,2,3].map((n) => (
  <Composite>
    <h2>Title {n}</h2>
    <p>Description {n}</p>
  </Composite>
))};
```

Of course, react-composite has to be installed.

```
npm install react-composite --save
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `createFragment` here. See *[Keyed Fragments](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/create-fragment.html)*.

```
import createFragment from 'react-addons-create-fragment';
...
{[1,2,3].map((n) => createFragment({
    h: <h3>...</h3>,
    p: <p>...</p>
  })
)}
```

(I am using [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) and [JSX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)#JSX) syntax here.)

You first have to add the `react-addons-create-fragment` package:

```
npm install --save react-addons-create-fragment
```

The *advantage* over [Jan Olaf Krems's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840997/how-can-i-return-multiple-lines-jsx-in-another-return-statement-in-react/23841059#23841059): React does not complain about the missing `key`.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong but you can simply add the keys manually. using jan's example: first array item gets e.g. <h3 key={i}></h3> and second array item sth slightly different like <p> key={i + '-foo'}></p>

Answer (score 2):

It is simple by React fragment `<></>` and `React.Fragment`:

```
return (
    <>
      {[1, 2, 3].map(
        (n, index): ReactElement => (
          <React.Fragment key={index}>
            <h3>Item {n}</h3>
            <p>Description {n}</p>
          </React.Fragment>
        ),
      )}
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you are not on the current project folder or the folder you are currently on contains more than one project, you probably will get this error.

I had a similar error and once switched to a current project folder and run, the issue is gone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).