# How to render two components in single id element in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How to render more than on component in single id,i know that single id can not render more than one component, i also tried `getElementByClass` but the result was same

```
    function Ads(product) {
        return(
          <div className={product.className} id="user-ads">
         <div className = "col-sm-6 col-md-5">
          <div className = "thumbnail">
          <img src={product.image} alt="product-image"/>
          </div>
          <div className = "caption">
          <div className="border">
             <h3>{product.title}</h3>
             <p>{product.desc}</p>  
                <button className = "btn btn-primary" role = "button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-detail">View Details
                </button>  
                  </div>
                    </div>
                      </div>
                        </div>

          );
    }

    function Newad(product) {
        return (
          <Ads title="Forza" desc="rndom text rndom text rndom text rndom text" image="img/img2.jpg" />
          );

}

ReactDOM.render(<Ads title="PlayStation 4" desc="Lorem ipsum jipsum Lorem ipsum jipsum" image="img/img1.jpg" className="row" />, document.getElementById('all_ads'));
ReactDOM.render(<Newad />, document.getElementById('all_ads'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do that? That is not how react works. There should be a single mount point and all other components should be under that mount point

So in your case when you render `Newad` it automatically calls `Ads` which is declared inside Newad.

If you want to list multiple ads passed parameters to your add components from `NewAd` not by rendering it again through different id.

Comment: can you demonstrate me i'm confused i just want  to render the Newad in the Ads component so they share same parent div

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Now the `Newad` components are displayed in `Ads` component.

Answer (score 0):

Would either of the two solutions below work for your intended use?

Also, you may find this question useful: [Return multiple elements inside React.render()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34893506/return-multiple-elements-inside-react-render)

**Solution 1:** http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/RGoJvB

```
function Newad(product) {
  return (
    <div className={product.className} id="user-ads">
      <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-5">
        <div className="thumbnail">
          <img src={product.image} alt="product-image"/>
        </div>
        <div className="caption">
          <div className="border">
            <h3>{product.title}</h3>
            <p>{product.desc}</p>  
            <button className="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-detail">
              View Details
            </button>  
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function Ads() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Newad title="Forza" desc="rndom text rndom text rndom text rndom text" image="https://placeimg.com/200/200/nature" className="row" />
      <Newad title="PlayStation 4" desc="Lorem ipsum jipsum Lorem ipsum jipsum" image="https://placeimg.com/200/200/tech" className="row" />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Ads />, document.getElementById('all_ads'));
```

**Solution 2:** http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/NRbBrA
Alternatively you could store your ads in an array of objects and then iterate through them using `map()` method.

Here is the code:

```
const ADS = [
  {
    title: "Forza",
    desc: "rndom text rndom text rndom text rndom text",
    image: "https://placeimg.com/200/200/nature",
    className: "row"
  },
  {
    title: "PlayStation 4",
    desc: "Lorem ipsum jipsum Lorem ipsum jipsum",
    image: "https://placeimg.com/200/200/tech",
    className: "row"
  },      
];


function Ads() {
  return (
    <div>
      {ADS.map((product, index) => {
        return (          
          <div key={index} className={product.className} id="user-ads" >
            <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-5">
              <div className="thumbnail">
                <img src={product.image} alt="product-image"/>
              </div>
              <div className="caption">
                <div className="border">
                  <h3>{product.title}</h3>
                  <p>{product.desc}</p>  
                  <button className="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-detail">
                    View Details
                  </button>  
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>              
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<Ads />, document.getElementById('all_ads'));
```

Comment: Ideally you should not even do this way. Create an object with data and run map over it, instead of manually calling it 2 times. What if there 100 of newads.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @HarkiratSaluja, I've added this approach to my answer.