# Conditionally render list with Higher Order Component

Tags: reactjs, jsx

My app has a feature toggle functionality that tells my UI whether or not a piece of UI should be rendered. I would like to create a Higher Order Component to conditionally render these types of components. In one scenario, I'm trying to conditionally render a list, but I'm running into this error:

```
ConditionalRender(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
```

This makes sense since I just am trying to render the children of this component. Here's what I've got so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/cykmyabL/

```
var settings = { showHello: true, showGoodbye: false};

function ConditionalRender (props) {
    var output = null;

  if(props.shouldRender) output = props.children;

  console.log(output);
  // return (<li>{output}</li>); // This works, but isn't desired html structure
  return ({output});
}

function App (props) {
    return (
    <ul>
        <ConditionalRender shouldRender={props.settings.showHello}>
        <li>Hello!</li>
      </ConditionalRender>
      <ConditionalRender shouldRender={props.settings.showGoodbye}>
          <li>Goodbye...</li>
        </ConditionalRender>
    </ul>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App settings={settings} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

If I can help it, I would just like to render the children without any additional logic.This HOC would also handle more complex children down the line. Something like this:

```
<ConditionalRender shouldRender={props.settings.showHello}>
<div>
<p> blah blah blah</p>
<table>
<!-- ... -->
</table>
</div>
</ConditionalRender>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In the case of conditionally rendering `<li>` items - it seems like this would be better handled by having your `<li>` data in an Array. That way you could use an array method like [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove the items you don't want rendered in JSX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function App(props) {
  return (
    <ul>        
      {props.settings.showHello && <li>Hello!</li>}
      {props.settings.showGoodbye && <li>Goodbye...</li>}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

**P.S.** Your code doesn't work because of this line:

```js
return ({output});
```

Assuming you have es2015 support, it would be treated as [object property shorthand](http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand). So it's the same as:

```js
return {output: output};
```

which is not what React expects to get from the `render` method.

You could try this:

```js
function ConditionalRender(props) {
  if (props.shouldRender) {
    // Make sure we have only a single child
    return React.Children.only(props.children);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

But this is not the simplest way. See more [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

**P.P.S.** Your ConditionalRender component is not what is called Higher-Order Component. According to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html), HOC is a *function that takes a component and returns a new component*.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! Could you tell me why returning `props.children` wouldn't work, but `React.Children.only(props.children)` will? Is it because I wrapped the `output` with brackets/parens?

Also, thanks for the tip on HOC. I'll continue to educate myself.

Comment: Both versions will work, `React.Children.only` is just a recommendation. Brackets are the reason of the error.

Comment: Finally:
`return {props.children}` doesn't work.
`return ({props.children})` doesn't work.
`return props.children` works when there is only a single child.
`return React.Children.only(props.children)` works if there is a single child and throws an exception with a clear message otherwise.

Comment: Makes sense. Is there a way to render nested children or adjacent children?

Comment: **TL;DR** No way without wrapping them into a single node.
See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34893506/return-multiple-elements-inside-react-render)

Comment: Good tips. Thanks again for all your help!