# React.Js - Part of the DOM does not render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, jsx

So I on thid days I started studying REACT.JS.

Look at code below:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './style.css'
const react = {
    imgSrc: 'https://camo.githubusercontent.com/abd19bd0c5030c8d874ed7073f1815d777004451d5967c447386840b80624569/68747470733a2f2f63646e2e61757468302e636f6d2f626c6f672f72656163742d6a732f72656163742e706e67',
    title: "React",
}
const angular = {
    imgSrc: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cf/Angular_full_color_logo.svg/1200px-Angular_full_color_logo.svg.png',
    title: 'Angular',
}
const MyApp = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <All imgSrc={react.imgSrc} title={react.title} />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <All imgSrc={angular.imgSrc} title={angular.title} />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
const All = (props) => {
    return (
        <img src={props.imgSrc} alt="none" />,
        <h1>{props.title}</h1>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <MyApp />, document.getElementById('root')
)
```

So everything working good except 1 thing

**Problem**:

The img tag does not render.

[image: The Render Result Image]

Comment: Put the component `All` above `MyApp` you will probably get a reference error otherwise. Also the return of `All` is invalid. If you mean to return two elements use a react fragment. At the moment it's using the comma which only returns the h1 element

Comment: Problem is solved  Thank you evolutionbox and others

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return multiple elements inside React.render()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34893506/return-multiple-elements-inside-react-render)

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning a single JSX element in your `All` component. Change to:

```
const All = (props) => {
    return (
       <div>
        <img src={props.imgSrc} alt="none" />
        <h1>{props.title}</h1>
       </div>
    )
}
```

or you can use <> and </> instead of div, which stands for React Fragment

Comment: btw, this question has been asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34893506/return-multiple-elements-inside-react-render

Comment: Cool, you can flag the question as duplicate :D

Comment: (let's both do that :D )

Comment: just did :) I believe you don't need to comment this question has been asked before to every answer, the mods will flag the question as duplicate even if it has been only flagged once.

Comment: (ok cool, I just thought I'd let you know) (I'm whispering btw)

Answer (score 0):

Fix the render of the **All** component.
The comma operator evaluates from left to right and returns the last statement.
You are basically returning only the h1 element.
[Comma operator (,)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Here is a working example
https://jsfiddle.net/vc5dr9y7/

```
const All = (props) => {
    return (<React.Fragment>
          <img src={props.imgSrc} alt="none" />
          <h1>{props.title}</h1>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Comment: btw, this question has been asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34893506/return-multiple-elements-inside-react-render