# Navbar not rendering | requiring navbar on only one page, not globally

Tags: reactjs

I have a navbar that I only want to render on my SignUp page.
However, currently, this navbar is not rendering at all on my sign up page, despite attempting to render it  via `<TopNav />`

I do not want it globally, so am not including in my App.js.

How can I get this navbar to render on only my signup page?

Top Nav

```
import Logo from '../Logo.svg'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";


export default class TopNav extends Component {
    render () {
        return  (
 
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
          <div className="container">
          <Link to = '/'> 
    <div>
      <img src ={Logo} alt='Logo' className='Logo'/>
    </div>
  </Link>          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
              <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link className="nav-link" to={"/sign-in"}>Login</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link className="nav-link" to={"/sign-up"}>Sign up</Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        );
    }};
```

SignUp page

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import TopNav from "./TopNav"

export default class SignUp extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          
          <div>
            
<TopNav />
          </div>,
                <div className="auth-wrapper">
                <div className="auth-inner">
            <form>
              
            <h4>Sign Up</h4>
            <p>
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.
            </p>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>First name</label>
              <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="First name" />
            </div>
</form>
          </div>
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Here is also my current app.js for reference

```
function App() {
  return (

    <div className="App">
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<AppLayout />}/>
                    <Route index element={<Home />} />           
                     <Route path="/sign-in" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/sign-up" element={<SignUp />} />
          </Routes>

</div>
  );
}
```

Update

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import TopNav from "./TopNav"

export default class SignUp extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
        
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          
<TopNav />
<div className="auth-wrapper">
              <div className="auth-inner">
        </div>
            
          <form>
            
          <h4>Sign Up</h4>
          <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
          </p>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>First name</label>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="First name" />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Last name</label>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Last name" />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Email address</label>
            <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" />
          </div>
          <p classname="forgot-password text-right">
            Already registered <a href="/sign-in">log in?</a>
          </p>
          <button type="submit" className="button">Sign Up</button>
        
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Unless there is code that isn't shown above the `TopNav` class, it looks like you're missing `import React, { Component } from "react";`

Comment: @HudsonGraeme Yeah, I have that in the TopNav. Code was just missing

Answer (score 0):

There is a comma in the render function of the `signUp` component that causes two components to be returned from the signUp page. The last component is rendered and the first is ignored. The code should be as follows:

[image: Edit TopNav]

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TopNav from "./TopNav";

export default class SignUp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <> {/*Use react fragment to wrap the nav and auth sections*/}
        <div>
          <TopNav />
        </div> {/*Remove the `,`*/}
        <div className="auth-wrapper">
          <div className="auth-inner">
            <form>
              <h4>Sign Up</h4>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.</p>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label>First name</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  placeholder="First name"
                />
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

See this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34893582/10538100

Comment: Did not seem to work? removing comma did nothing. See edit with code. Am I overlooking something? I feel like I must be

Comment: Hmm I placed your updated code in the codesandbox and it works perfectly without the comma. Please have a look at this [App.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/topnav-dhzgwx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/App.js) and see if the changes made there might help as well.