# Return multiple <tr> lines in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to be able to return 2 `<tr>` lines, which works by wrapping in a `<tbody>` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840997/how-to-return-multiple-lines-jsx-in-another-return-statement-in-react):

```
var Item = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <tbody>
                <tr>/*...*/</tr>
                <tr>/*...*/</tr>
            </tbody>
        );  
    }   
});
```

However, I get a warning from React: ***< tbody> cannot appear as a child of < tbody>***

Is there any other way to do this that would be more DOM friendly?

Comment: @AkshatMahajan: Likely just a typo in the post, otherwise the code would not even be parsed (because syntax error).

Comment: Sorry, yes that was a typo in the post.

Comment: Have you tried appending it to <table> instead of <tbody>? I've written a lot of HTML tables in the past & have never been forced by any browser to use these 3 tags: <thead>, <tbody> or <tfoot>. They're optional & <th> and <td>  tags work for separating header vs. body cells, respectively. Besides, most people have gotten away from <table> tags & switched to <div> tags, as <table> tags cause conflicts with CSS. Only tabular data still needs <table> tags.

Comment: @Clomp https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

Comment: Yes, that's tabular data, since it fits inside of a spreadsheet like grid.

Answer (score 3):

That's an annoying limitation of React right now. A `<table>` can contain multiple `<tbody>` though -- would rendering `<Item>` as an additional `<tbody>` within `<table>` work for you?

Comment: A good example of using 3x table divisions would include using `<thead>`, `<tbody>` & `<tfoot>`, rather than 3x `<tbody>` tags. See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tbody.asp

Comment: Those have totally different semantics. The OP appears to need rows in the body.

Comment: I realized I was using the `Item` component within another `<tbody>`, which is what was causing the warning.  Removing that additional outer `<tbody>` resolved the warning.  Still, it would be nice to be able to return 2 `<tr>` without being wrapped in a `<tbody>`, as CSS applied to an n-th `<tr>` doesn't work with this.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're running into the maximum JSX root node problem. There can only be 1 root node in the return, but it can have any number of child nodes. So try this:

```
var Item = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <table> /* <- This is the root node. */
                <thead> /* <- Multiple nodes start at this level. */
                    <tr>/*...*/</tr>
                    <tr>/*...*/</tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>/*...*/</tr>
                    <tr>/*...*/</tr>
                    <tr>/*...*/</tr>
                    <tr>/*...*/</tr>
                    <tr>/*...*/</tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>/*...*/</tr>
                    <tr>/*...*/</tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        );  
    }   
});
```

Comment: It's easy to solve if you can generate the whole table in a single component, the problem is when you need to delegate representation of several rows in a container to a component.