# reactjs returning multiple divs

Tags: reactjs

Instead of returning a nested element.

```
<div>
    <div className="one">one</div>
    <div className="two">two</div>
</div>
```

how do I just return this

```
<div className="one">one</div>
<div className="two">two</div>
```

Comment: You just can't render more than a single element, this is not suppose to work this way. Why would you do it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return multiple lines JSX in another return statement in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840997/how-to-return-multiple-lines-jsx-in-another-return-statement-in-react)

Comment: Do you ever read the documentation or use the search function before asking??

Comment: -- its the way the markup is - for handling the bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

Like @Glenn Reyes mentioned, in react 16 you can do this

```
return [
  <li key="1">One</li>,
  <li key="2">Two</li>,
  <li key="3">Three</li>
];
```

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of React ([v15](https://github.com/facebook/react/releases/tag/v15.5.4)), you can't return multiple Elements from render.

In the upcoming major version ([React v16](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8854)), you will be able to [return arrays with multiple Elements from render](https://youtu.be/QW5TE4vrklU?t=7m15s)

If you want to try it now, you can do so buy `npm install react@next --save` or via yarn with `yarn add react@next`