# React passing div up the components

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I'm completely new React. I have done the tutorials but as always reading and doing are two seperate things. 
So starting a brand new app from scratch and have fallen at the first hurdle.

I have a component called AnswerBox and a component called GetAnswerButton but the html in GetAnswerButton is not being rendered so I assume its not being passed to the AnswerBox component. Only the AnswerBox html is being rendered. So question, could anyone please point out the error of my ways

```
 import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import './index.css';


    class AnswerBox extends React.Component{

        render(){
            return(
                <GetAnswerButton />,
                <div className="answerBox"></div>
             )
        }
    }

    class GetAnswerButton extends React.Component {

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <button>Click Me</button>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
        <AnswerBox />,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

Heres a code pen of it working(or not working!!)
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/barryw33/pen/jzvXpW)

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [how-to-return-multiple-lines-jsx-in-another-return-statement-in-react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840997/how-to-return-multiple-lines-jsx-in-another-return-statement-in-react/48515131#48515131)

Comment: You will find the answer in the link above. Either place `GetAnswerButton />` and the div inside an array, wrap them in a div, or use `React.Fragment`. Also, even though it's not correct, do use `<div className="answerBox" />` (self-closing tag). It is considered better practise.

Comment: have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31284169/5476782) question also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class AnswerBox extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
     <div>
       <GetAnswerButton />
       <div className="answerBox"></div>
     <div>
    )
  }
}
```

wrap your return inside AnswerBox with `div` or `Fragment` and it works. 
or put it inside `[]` because you return as array.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something really obvious I was missing

Comment: Glad to help. Most of time is something obvious, sometimes you just need to go for walk for 5 min and to refresh your brain :)

Answer (score 1):

try to update the code in the AnswerBox class as follows:

```
class AnswerBox extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <GetAnswerButton />,
        <div className="answerBox"></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

You should have an error in console saying adjacent elements need to be wrapped into an enclosing one. Or similar.

Comment: Thanks I knew it was something really obvious I was missing

Comment: glad it helped!