# How to write the complicated rendering loop in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am writing a nested loop in React.  All I am seeing is the final return statements of

tags. Where are the  and  going? Thank you.

```
{ this.state.data.headings.map( (heading, i) =>
    <h3 key={i}>{heading}</h3> &&
      // some headings do not have subheadings, tho
      // they still have statements. deal with these cases first...
      ((this.state.data.subheadings[i].length === 0 &&
        this.state.data.statements[i].map((statement, _j) =>
          <p key={i+_j}>{statement}</p>)) ||
        // cases where the group of statements has a subheading...
        (this.state.data.subheadings[i].map((subheading, j) =>
          <h4 key={i + j}>{subheading}</h4> &&
          this.state.data.statements[i][j].map((statement, k) =>
            <p key={i+j+k}>{statement}</p>))
        )
      )
    )
  }
```

Comment: please explain more, I am not getting what is your exact problem.

Comment: Do you have a more complete code example?

Comment: What do you mean "final return statements of tags"? Also separate out your logic/components, the code is getting dense and hard to read

Answer (score 1):

A better way of doing this in my opinion is to separate this in different components each one of them taking care of one of the loops.in your case header,subheader,statement, etc.

Comment: Prefer comments to suggest improvements or opinion.

Answer (score 1):

There is everything ok with you code, except you can refactor it to make more readable. 
Don't repeat yourself (DRY), always move duplicated code to separate component, in your example it is `statement` element. Also, i remove redundant `key` props.

```
render() {
    const {headings, subheadings, statements} = this.state;

    return headings.map((heading, i) =>
        <div key={i}>
            <h3>{heading}</h3>
            {
                subheadings[i].length
                    ? subheadings[i].map((subheading, j) =>
                        <div key={j}>
                            <h4>{subheading}</h4>
                            <Statements statements={statements[i][j]}/>
                        </div>
                    )
                    : <Statements statements={statements[i]}/>
            }
        </div>
    );
}

const Statements = ({statements}) => (
    statements.map((statement, i) =>
        <p key={i}>{statement}</p>
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

(omg folks,) feels like i had to take a picture to prove it...

**solution, special thanks to** [a similar Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840997/how-to-return-multiple-lines-jsx-in-another-return-statement-in-react) (I'm using React v15 out of an older template for Ether dApps)

```
{ headings.map( (heading, i) =>
      [ <h3 key={i}>{heading}</h3>,
        subheadings[i].length === 0 ?
          statements[i][0].map( (statement, j) =>
            <p key={j}>{statement}</p>,
          ) :
        subheadings[i].map( (subheading, j) => (
          [<h4 key={j}>{subheading}</h4>,
          statements[i][j].map( (statement, k) =>
            <p key={k} style={{color: 'green'}}>{statement}</p> )
          ]
        ))
      ])
}
```

[image: screenshot of editor and browser]