# React jsx - Getting unexpected token error for conditional rendering inside the map function

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to put some conditional logic inside the map function in render function. I am rendering a tabels and would like to check if the table needs a title, and if it needs just render it. This is the part where I am trying to do this:

```
const tableTitle = receiver.receiverType === receiverTypes.ARBG ? receiver.receiverNumber : null;
          return (
            { tableTitle }
```

And this is the part of the component where I have tried to put this:

```
const AccountingTable = ({ result, toggleDetails, showDetails }) => {
  const rangeOfMonths = getRangeOfMonths(
    result.periodFrom,
    result.nexPeriodTo ? result.nexPeriodTo: result.periodeTo,
  );
  return (
    <div className={styles.table}>
      {
        result.periodsPerReceiver.map((receiver, receiverIndex) => {
          const tableTitle = receiver.receiverType === receiverTypes.ARBG ? receiver.receiverNumber : null;
          return (
            { tableTitle }
            <Table
              headerTextCodes={getHeaderCodes(
                showCollapseButton(receiver.resultatPerField),
                { toggleDetails, showDetails: showDetails[mottakerIndex] ? showDetails[receiverIndex].show : false, receiverIndex},
                rangeOfMonths,
                result.nexPeriodTo,
              )}
              allowFormattedHeader
              key={`tableIndex${receiverIndex+ 1}`}
            >
```

But, I get the error:

> Unexpected token, expected ,

Why, I am getting this error, how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping what you return from the map function in e.g. `React.Fragment`?

Comment: Can you post a complete block code? 'Cause actually we can't se the nodes hierarchy

Comment: Your code has an extra `,` in `result.nexPeriodTo,` removing it should fix one of . your issue. you would also need to wrap `{ tableTitle }
            <Table
              headerTextCodes={getHeaderCodes(
                showCollapseButton(receiver.resultatPerField),
                { toggleDetails, showDetails: showDetails[mottakerIndex] ? showDetails[receiverIndex].show : false, receiverIndex},
                rangeOfMonths,
                result.nexPeriodTo,
              )}` within `React.Fragment` or return them as an array.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840997/how-to-return-multiple-lines-jsx-in-another-return-statement-in-react/48515131#48515131

Comment: wrapping the whole block inside return helped