# react JSX when to use () and when to use {}

Tags: reactjs

I'm really struggling to understand what's wrong with the syntax in the following react function

```
    const listItem = (parentId) => {
            var childCategories = categories.filter(category => category.ParentId === parentId)
            return (
                childCategories.map(category => (
                    <ListItem key={category.Id} button>
                        <ListItemText primary={category.Name} />
                    </ListItem>
                    listItem(category.Id) //// it doesn't like this line
                ))
            )
        }
```

if I take out the line with the comment "//// it doesn't like this line" the function works except of course there is no recursion. I've tried all different combinations of {} and() e.g. {listItem(category.Id)} but it still doesn't work. Any idea what's wrong with the syntax.

Comment: try this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx

Comment: Can you include the whole component in your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return multiple lines JSX in another return statement in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840997/how-to-return-multiple-lines-jsx-in-another-return-statement-in-react)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a syntax error and not related to React, in [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) you can only return a single expression.

```
return [[expression]];
```

What you have written is similar to:

```
array.map(item => { 
 return (item item) // syntax error
})
```

So in this case for React, to return a single value you can use [`React.Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactfragment):

```
<>
  <ListItem key={category.Id} button>
    <ListItemText primary={category.Name} />
  </ListItem>
  {listItem(category.Id)}
</>
```